# Highcharts not working in UpdatePanel of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, updatepanel

I drawn a highchart in asp.net. I was working properly but when I puts my SUBMIT button in updatepanel then highchart is not working.It is not redrawing.
Page is not reloaded so it is not redrawing.

aspx code-

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update1">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="button_borrowing_calculate" CssClass="SDButtonGrad" runat="server" Text="Calculate>>" Height="30px" Width="90px" OnClientClick="emptycheck();" OnClick="btn_bp_calculate_Click" /></ContentTemplate>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatep">
            <ContentTemplate>
                          <div id="rp_graph1" style="height: auto; width: 100%;" runat="server">
                                                <highchart:LineChart runat="server" Height="300px" Width="99%" ID="hcLine" />
                                            </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

aspx.cs code -

```
   protected void btn_bp_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    hcLine.Title.text = "Borrowing Capacity";
    hcLine.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("Amount") });
    hcLine.XAxis.Add(new XAxisItem
    {
        categories = new[] { "0","1", "2","3", "4","5", "6","7", "8","9", "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30",
                                                            "31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50"
                                                        }
    });

    var series = new List<Serie>();
    series.Add(new Serie { data = new object[] { 400, 435, 446, 479, 554, 634, 687, 750, 831 } });
    //bind 
    hcLine.DataSource = series;
    hcLine.DataBind();




}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: no errors......i think clientscript is not reloading and because of this graph is not redrawing in update panel. The graph div is empty after calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx code is not very clear. But i ll write two suggestion and try one of them

If your button is outside the update Panel so try this way:

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
 <ContentTemplate>
<div id="rp_graph1" style="height: auto; width: 100%;" runat="server">
  <highchart:LineChart runat="server" Height="300px" Width="99%" ID="hcLine" />
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button_borrowing_calculate" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

if your button is inside the update panel set the attribute childrenAsTrigger to true

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
```

Comment: I think Highchart is not redrawing because clientscript is not loading without reloading page. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an AsyncPostBackTrigger use a **PostBackTrigger**.
Usually I register it in the Page_load method.

This is a short example where I've used the dotnet.HighCharts component.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:Literal ID="chrtMyChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

For the call:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnRefresh);

    Render_Chart("%");
}
```

**Render_Chart** is the method that generate the chart.
It is called also pressing the button **btnRefresh**

If you want a complete example try to give a look [at this post](http://www.balsamino.com/component/k2/35-dotnet-highcharts-inside-updatepanel.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no accepted answer so thought of writing the solution I went for so someone else can use it.

Source is http://www.balsamino.com/programming/39-highcharts-dotnet-and-updatepanel-a-complete-solution.html

Basically, in web forms with updatepanels, simply doing litxxx.text = mydontnethighchartsoutput() does not work.

All you have to do is from your dotnethighcharts function, return two things:
1. chart1.ChartContainerHtmlString().ToString
2. chart1.ChartScriptHtmlString().ToString

Put the output from 1. to a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (with last parameter = FALSE saying you do not want a script block added as chart1.ChartContainerHtmlString().ToString will do it for you

Put the output from 2. to your literal like 
LitMyLiteral.text  = chart1.ChartScriptHtmlString().ToString

Hope that helps :)